# Weird Output in C while printf()

Tags: mysql, c

I have a piece of code that I made.

```
char statement_usr[150];
char statement_res[150];

char total_string_usn[100] = "";
strcat(total_string_usn, "'");
strcat(total_string_usn, u);
strcat(total_string_usn, "'");

strcat(total_string_usn, ",");

strcat(total_string_usn, "'");
strcat(total_string_usn, p);
strcat(total_string_usn, "'");


printf("Total string USN: %s\n", total_string_usn);

char total_string_res[100] = "";
strcat(total_string_res, "'");
strcat(total_string_res, u);
strcat(total_string_res, "'");
strcat(total_string_res, ",");
strcat(total_string_res, "5000");
strcat(total_string_res, ",");
strcat(total_string_res, "0");
strcat(total_string_res, ",");
strcat(total_string_res, "0");
strcat(total_string_res, ",");
strcat(total_string_res, "0");

printf("Total string RES: %s\n", total_string_res);

snprintf(statement_usr, 150, "INSERT INTO users VALUES(%s)", total_string_usn);
snprintf(statement_res, 150, "INSERT INTO resources VALUES(%s)", total_string_res);

printf("Statement USR: %s\n" , statement_usr);
printf("Statement RES: %s\n" , statement_res);
```

With that being out there,here is the output:

```
    ' tal string USN: 'Wat','The
Total string RES: 'Wat',5000,0,0,0
' )tement USR: INSERT INTO users VALUES('Wat','The
Statement RES: INSERT INTO resources VALUES('Wat',5000,0,0,0)
```

No matter what I do, the USR line is always cut off, and when it is inserted in the database, the p variable comes out successfully but the first part is cut off by 4. So, if I make u Sunny it will display |y. The second string however gets inserted perfectly with nothing cut off.

What is this?

Comment: Where have you defined `u`?

Comment: You probably need to look up the `snprintf()` function — it would make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: And you shouldn't be building queries like this. You're open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: The output looks like you have DOS line endings in the variables `u` or `p`, either or both of them.  That is, there is probably a CR (carriage return, `'\r'`) in the data, causing the odd printout with some of the data that should be at the end overwriting data at the beginning.

Comment: You aren't checking the return values of snprintf

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the data returned is straight from a socket. Both 'u' and 'p'. But 'p' formats right while 'u' does not. Probably the \r at the end... will check in on that. How would I remove it?

Comment: Hmmm; straight from a socket — does the code add a null terminator when the data is written (the other program), or when the data is read (this program)?  Have you done a byte-by-byte hex dump of the value in `u`?  Have you tried `if (strchr(u, '\r') != 0) printf("There's a CR lurking in u!\n");`?  Is this program running on Windows or Unix?  Is the other program running on a different platform?  Are you getting line endings mapped? Write (or find) yourself a buffer dumper function and use it; it will save you hours of angst if you can identify reliably what's in the buffers your working with.

Comment: Note, too, that we're assuming that you know that there's enough space in your variables for the data — and so's your code.  I don't think you're seeing a buffer overflow problem, but your code is far from being protected against buffer overflows.  That will need to be fixed after you've dealt with the current problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sorry for the spelling errors. I am running on about 22hrs of no sleep. Yes, there was chars lurking in there '\r'. I separated it by inserting and formatting command:var1:var2:sep  and I took the sep out by only strtok command, var1 and var2.  Thank you very much, please close. Lookin back on it, that was a stupid question.

Comment: Also, remember that if the user name in `u` is "`Martin O'Rourke`", your SQL has problems.  And the problems are worse if the name is "`Martin O'; DELETE FROM Orders; --`" (see [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327)).